Are Math Questions about Replicating Paper Off-topic?
I found this allometry paper very interesting and wanted to enter the values for some species into their equations. However, the values I am getting are not what the authors list. Would it be off-topic to post a question asking what part of my math I am messing up?

Depends, but if it's specifcially on a piece of code, I'd consider Bioinformatics, or StackOverflow

I think it's likely to be on-topic, though I'd check a few times to make sure you're having some issue with interpreting the biology of the situation and application of math to that biology and not just code, as AliceD suggests, or mere algebra.
